# フォルダのファイル一覧を取得したい

Tags: monaca, cordova

Cordova apiを使ってあるフォルダのファイル一覧の取得をしたいのですが、

```
dir.rootDir = "a2015/";
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0
    , function(fileSystem) {
        dir.root = fileSystem.root;
        //フォルダがなければ作成
        dir.root.getDirectory(dir.rootDir, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(success) {}, fail); 
        // dirオブジェクトのcreateReaderメソッドを使い，
        // ディレクトリ内のファイルを読み込むためのDirectoryReaderオブジェクトを作成
        var directoryReader = dir.root.createReader();
        // ディレクトリ内のエントリを読み込み，コールバック関数に配列として渡す
        directoryReader.readEntries(function(success) {
            dir.files = success;
        });
    }
);
```

作成される a2015/ 内のファイルを一覧を作成するようにしたい場合、どのようにすればよいでしょうか。。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 現状はどこまでできているのでしょうか？または、上記のコードのどこかでエラーが出ている状態でしょうか。詳細を教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: エラーは出ていないのですが、作成フォルダの親階層内の一覧しか取得できないので、作成したフォルダ内の一覧を取得したいです。

Answer (score 1):

DirectoryReaderを生成すべきオブジェクトが違うと思います。

```
dir.rootDir = "a2015/";
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
    function(fileSystem) {
        dir.root = fileSystem.root;
        //フォルダがなければ作成
        dir.root.getDirectory(dir.rootDir, {create: true, exclusive: false},
            function(d) {
            // dオブジェクトのcreateReaderメソッドを使い，
            // ディレクトリ内のファイルを読み込むためのDirectoryReaderオブジェクトを作成
                var directoryReader = d.createReader();
                // ディレクトリ内のエントリを読み込み，コールバック関数に配列として渡す
                directoryReader.readEntries(function(success) {
                    dir.files = success;
                });
            },
            function(err) {}
        ); 
    }
);
```